# How do I copy 3 different types of files from different directories in 3 separate folders?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs

If you want to know how I solved it, go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43257926/copying-files-from-a-hdfs-directory-to-another-with-oozie-distcp-action/43307956#43307956).

The structure of my directories is as follows. Inside data directory I have folders named like `date_latter`. Inside, there are gz compressed files. I only need files for one date(current) that end with mta.gz and dfr.gz. Every `date_latter` folder has a different number of these files. I need to copy mta files to a folder named mta and dfr files to dfr folder. I would prefer that they remain compressed, but if not that's okey too.

```
data
--20170202_A
----20170202A(some_random_string)mta.gz
----20170202A(some_random_string)dfr.gz
----20170202A(some_random_string)crr.gz
--20170202_B
----20170202B(some_random_string)mta.gz
----20170202B(some_random_string)dfr.gz
----20170202B(some_random_string)crr.gz
--20170202_C
--20170203_A
--20170203_B
--20170203_C
--20170201_A
--20170201_B
--20170201_C
```

Currently I have

```
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val conf = new Configuration()
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

    val mta = "mta"
    val rcr = "dfr"
    val sub = "sub"

    val inPath = "/user/comverse/data/20170404_*/*" + mta + ".gz"

val fs = FileSystem.get( conf )
val fromPath = fs.globStatus(new Path(inPath))
for(path <- fromPath) {
      sc.textFile(path.getPath.toString).saveAsTextFile("/apps/hive/warehouse/adoc.db/fct_evkuzmin/file_" + mta)
//      println(path.getPath)
    }
    sc.stop()
  }
```

When I try to run println(path.getPath) I get the paths to all mta files, but when I try to actually copy

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory hdfs://nameservice1/apps/hive/warehouse/adoc.db/fct_evkuzmin/file_mta already exists
```

and fct_evkuzmin looks like

```
--/fct_evkuzmin/file_mta/_temporary/0/_temporary
----many folders named like `attempt_201704071536_0000_m_000000_0` with empty files inside
------attempt_201704071536_0000_m_000000_0(emty)
```

in the end I want

```
fct_evkuzmin
--file_mta
----20170202A(some_random_string)mta.gz
----20170202B(some_random_string)mta.gz
fct_evkuzmin
--file_dfr
----20170202A(some_random_string)dfr.gz
----20170202B(some_random_string)dfr.gz
```

Comment: If you just want to copy the files, why are you using Spark (which would load all their data into JVM memory)? It would probably be much more efficient to use HDFS API directly and not Spark (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38141516/how-to-move-or-copy-file-in-hdfs-by-using-java-api)

Comment: @Tzach I need to run it through oozie. I already have a working bash script with hadoop fs comands that does what I need, but when I tried running it in oozie it failed(because of file size it seems). I was adviced to use spark because it will definetly work. Will there be this problem with FileUtil?

Comment: "because of file size it seems" - I don't know what that problem was, but I don't see a reason not to be able to accomplish this with `FileUtil.copy`, it's not limited to small files...

Comment: Why don't you try `DistCp`?

Comment: @fran I did, but I have a problem and don't know how to solve it, so I am looking for alternatives. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43257926/copying-files-from-a-hdfs-directory-to-another-with-oozie-distcp-action

Comment: @Tzac I actually run that  bash script through Oozie once and it worked, but after, no matter how many times I tried, the same script did nothing. I asked my colleagues and they told me it's a common problem they don't have a solution for. I will try FileUtil.copy.