# Java Copying File in HDFS to another Directory in HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I'm using the example in this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38141516/how-to-move-or-copy-file-in-hdfs-by-using-java-api) to copy contents from one directory in hdfs to another directory in hdfs. The copying of file works, but it creates a new subdirectory in the target vs. just copying the file to the target dir. Example:

```
  Path source=new Path("hdfs://HANameService/sources/hpm_support/apc_code/");
  Path target=new Path("hdfs://HANameService/staging/hpm_support/apc_code/");
  FileSystem fs = source.getFileSystem(conf); 
  FileUtil.copy(fs, source, fs, target, true, conf);`
```

So instead of copying the file to `hdfs://HANameService/staging/hpm_support/apc_code` it creates a new dir under apc_code and the file ends up in `hdfs://HANameService/staging/hpm_support/apc_code/apc_code` How can I get it to not create that sub-directory?

Comment: Tried content wildcard, such as `Path source=new Path("hdfs://HANameService/sources/hpm_support/apc_code/*");`?

Comment: Alternatively, have you tried to specify just the parent for the destination? ` Path source=new Path("hdfs://HANameService/sources/hpm_support/apc_code/");  Path target=new Path("hdfs://HANameService/staging/hpm_support/");`? That could work.

Comment: OK Your first suggestion results in: File does not exist: hdfs://HA-NameService/sources/hpm_support/apc_code/*

Comment: Second suggestion results in: java.io.IOException: Target hdfs://HA-NameService/staging/hpm_support/apc_code is a directory

Comment: Isn't that because the target directory already exists?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to `list` the files in the `source directory` and `copy` each file using `iterator`

```
            Path source=new Path("hdfs://HANameService/sources/hpm_support/apc_code/");
            Path target=new Path("hdfs://HANameService/staging/hpm_support/apc_code/");
            FileSystem fs = source.getFileSystem(conf);
            RemoteIterator<LocatedFileStatus> sourceFiles = fs.listFiles(source, true);
            if(sourceFiles != null) {
                while(sourceFiles.hasNext()){
                    FileUtil.copy(fs, sourceFiles.next().getPath(), fs, target, true, conf);
                }           
            }
```

Hope it is helpful to you

Comment: You don't define "file" anywhere for file.listFiles

Comment: @jymbo. Would you mind correcting that. It was a typo mistake. I will accept the changes if you make. :)

Comment: Good stuff, cause `FileUtil.copy` does not accept wildcard character :(

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by @ernest_k this behavior only occurs if the target directory already exists in HDFS.

So, deleting the target directory before calling the `copy` method will also solve your problem:

```
if(fileSystem.exists(pathTo)) {
    fileSystem.delete(pathTo, true);
}

FileUtil.copy(fileSystem, pathFrom, fileSystem, pathTo, false, true, conf);
```