# HDFS commands in pyspark script

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hdfs

I am writing a simple pyspark script to copy hdfs files and folders from one location to another. I have gone through many docs and answers available online but i could not find a way to copy folders and files using pyspark or to execute hdfs commands using pyspark(particularly copy folders and files)

Below is my code

```
hadoop = sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop
Path = hadoop.fs.Path
FileSystem = hadoop.fs.FileSystem
conf = hadoop.conf.Configuration()
fs = FileSystem.get(conf)
source = hadoop.fs.Path('/user/xxx/data')
destination = hadoop.fs.Path('/user/xxx/data1')

if (fs.exists(Path('/user/xxx/data'))):
    for f in fs.listStatus(Path('/user/xxx/data')):
        print('File path', str(f.getPath()))
        **** how to use copy command here ?
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Java object for the [FileUtil class](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html) and use its copy methods, not hdfs script commands

[How to move or copy file in HDFS by using JAVA API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38141516/how-to-move-or-copy-file-in-hdfs-by-using-java-api#38142320)

It might be better to just use `distcp` rather than Spark, though, otherwise, you'll run into race conditions if you try to run that code with multiple executors